# there is a way to check the required role in the form data?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, multipartform-data, roles

i'm using nest js ..I check the require role from the body but now i have case who  make me need to check the require role in the form data, here is my role guard

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Role } from '../enums/role.enum';
import { ROLES_KEY } from '../decorators/roles.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (!requiredRoles) {

      return true;
    }
    
    const { body } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
   //console.log('==>', context.switchToHttp().getRequest())
   console.log('body should contain data ==>', body)

    console.log('should return true for role==>', requiredRoles.some((role) => body.role?.includes(role)))

    return requiredRoles.some((role) => body.role?.includes(role));
  }
}
```

i pass the role in the body but not working i get undefind

```
   @Post()
   @Roles(Role.Admin)
   @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
   @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('document'))
     async create(
   @UploadedFile() document: Express.Multer.File,
   @Body() createCandidats: CreateCandidats,
   @GetUser() user: User,
   @Body('role') role: string
   ): Promise<Candidate> {
   console.log("check the documents in express multer",document)
   console.log('1===>',createCandidats)
   const documentName = document.filename;
   console.log('2===>',document.filename)
   createCandidats.documents = documentName;
   console.log('role in the body===>',role)


   return await this.candidateService.create(createCandidats, user);
   }
```

in my request i find multipart/form data ... when i test without decorateur @Roles t work

Answer (score 0):

Can you also check whether the body exists and whether the role is defined?

For example

```
const { body } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
if (!body || !body.role) {
    return false;
}
return requiredRoles.some((role) => body.role.includes(role));
```

And also can you try add admin string into Roles decorator.

```
@Roles('admin')
```

and remove the role value in the body decorator.

```
@Body('role') role: string
```